# Problems with java @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) using MariaDB 10.4 and eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-5, mariadb-10.4

I am developing a REST web service in Java EE I am using: Glassfish 5.0 (build 25), MariaDB 10.4 and eclipselink (JPA 2.1)
here is my code:

### commande_line table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cooldb`.`commande_line` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quantity` INT NULL,
  `discount` INT NULL,
  `dish` INT NOT NULL,
  `commande` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_commande_line_dish1_idx` (`dish` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_commande_line_commande1_idx` (`commande` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_commande_line_dish1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dish`)
    REFERENCES `cooldb`.`dish` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_commande_line_commande1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`commande`)
    REFERENCES `cooldb`.`commande` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

### persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
  <!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
  <persistence-unit name="my_persistence_unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mariadb</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.yac.model.Address</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Commande</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.CommandeLine</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Dish</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Dishtype</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Ingredient</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Payement</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Profil</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Restaurant</class>
    <class>com.yac.model.Userapp</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### commandeline entity

```
public class CommandeLine implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;
    @Column(name = "discount")
    private Integer discount;
    @JoinColumn(name = "commande", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Commande commande;
    @JoinColumn(name = "dish", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Dish dish;
    //Constructor
    // Setter and Getter
}
```

### commandeline web service

```
@Stateless
@Path("commandeline")
public class CommandeLineFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<CommandeLine> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "my_persistence_unit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public CommandeLineFacadeREST() {
        super(CommandeLine.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void create(CommandeLine entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}
```

### AbstractFacade

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I test my web service with Postman and I try to insert a record with a POST request
here is what I receive as error message:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=158) Table 'cooldb.sequence' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQ_GEN_SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?") ...
```

I don't understand why the problem with SEQUANCE when I use @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY).
When I change with @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE) and I create the table with the following script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQUANCE START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

by applying the solution shown in : [Table 'customerjpa.sequence' doesn't exist JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141014/table-customerjpa-sequence-doesnt-exist-jpa)
but the same probleme

thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What database platform class is being used? Check that it has support for IDENTITY and/or SEQUENCE, otherwise EclipseLink will default to table sequencing. If you don't know the platform class used (you can specify it with the target-database persistence property) it should get logged during deployment when it tests the datasource to detect the DB.

Comment: Also note, IDENTITY != SEQUENCE. If you are creating a sequence "SEQUANCE" in the database and want it used, you must define it in JPA using the GeneratedValue to which points to a sequence definition AND the SequenceGenerator annotation to define the sequence itself. see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/GeneratedValue and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Ids/SequenceGenerator

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use MariaDB 10.4 and it supports both IDENTITY and SEQUENCE, but what I do not understand is the fact that it supports IDENTITY but it is as if it is always configured in SEQUENCE despite that I have chosen IDENTITY. excuse me for my level in english language

Comment: DatabasePlatform is an Eclipselink class that is extended to provide DB specific behaviour. The platform class you are using in your persistence unit must have identity and sequence support built in or it might default to using a sequence or table sequencing. What is the target database platform that was specified? https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_database.htm

Comment: It works thank you very much chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved using Chris comments, i just add the following line in my persistence.xml file:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
```

Thank you very much Chris.
So my new persistence.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
    <!-- Define Persistence Unit -->
    <persistence-unit name="my_persistence_unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mariadb</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.yac.model.Address</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Commande</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.CommandeLine</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Dish</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Dishtype</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Ingredient</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Payement</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Profil</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Restaurant</class>
        <class>com.yac.model.Userapp</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="MySQL"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I just specified the database platform in MySQL in the persistence.xml file of the moment MariaDB is based on it, because MariaDB is not mentioned in the list.
If there are other suggestions do not hesitate thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution:
Add `?useMysqlMetadata=true` to your JDBC URL connection as bellow:

```
<property name="URL" value="jdbc:mariadb://[HOST]:[PORT]/[DB NAME]?useMysqlMetadata=true"/>
```

that will make MariaDB use MySQL meta data and then eclipselink will detect it as MySQL.